# how to autoplay a video in uihtml matlab 2020a?

Tags: html, matlab

I am using uihtml in matlab to play a video,I  could embed a video in the uifigure,but it plays when I press the play button.
Is there a way to autoplay a video in uihtml in matlab?
my current HTML script looks like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body style="background-color:black;font-family:arial;">
        
        <video width="583" height="325" controls autoplay>
            <source src="./movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for this, 'muted' should be added with autoplay to enable autoplay in uihtml in matlab

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body style="background-color:black;font-family:arial;">
        
        <video width="583" height="325" autoplay muted loop>
            <source src="./movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
        
    </body>
</html>
```